# How can I integrate webconnector and my own website with using only PHP?

Tags: php, api, opencart, quickbooks

I am trying to integrate  webconnecter and my own website for automatically syncing from website to quickbook software..

I am trying **keith parmer's webconnecter** and his **php dev' kit**.But I think I need to create a web service with C# ,to connect each other..
(I am not fluent in C#.
I need a solve only from PHP..)
these are my references

http://www.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php?id=quickbooks
*and*
[http://developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/doc/​PDF/​QBWC_​proguide.pdf](http://developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/doc/%E2%80%8BPDF/%E2%80%8BQBWC_%E2%80%8Bproguide.pdf)

I think I am confusing through the lot of codes and reference guides...

Please some one help me to reach to the correct path.

Comment: I think you mean Keith Palmer, don't you?

Comment: oh sorry I changed it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the [QuickBooks PHP DevKit](http://consolibyte.com/downloads/quickbooks-php-devkit/), and follow the [quick start guide](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_php_consolibyte_webconnector_quickstart).

When you have questions, use the support forums:

- https://idnforums.intuit.com/categories.aspx?catid=56&entercat=y
- http://consolibyte.com/forum/

You might want to try the search too. There's like 100 other threads about QuickBooks and PHP out there already, and Google provides a ton of [QuickBooks PHP](https://www.google.com/search?q=quickbooks%20php) search results.